# In GitHub Actions - a PR is requiring a CI to be ran even though the commit consists of only files (.md) that are part of the paths-ignore:

Tags: github, github-actions

The repo and CI file are here:
https://github.com/microsoft/garnet
https://github.com/microsoft/garnet/blob/main/.github/workflows/ci.yml

We set up our GitHub Actions CI where we do not want our CIs to run when the only files changed are documentation (.md). The GH actions works as designed where it won't run in that case. However, the PRs require CIs to run and for some reason, the PR still expects CI to be ran and it won't allow the merge because it is waiting for the CI GH Action to finish. The GH Action never was fired off (by design) so it is just stuck and we have to "By pass branch protections" to make the merge happen.

How can we sync the PR to NOT require a CI when the CI isn't being ran?  This has to be a common problem.

One thought is to not to use paths-ignore: and instead filter it somehow.

My preference would be that the CIs wouldn't be required in that specific instance (where only .md files were changed in the PR).

Answer (score -1):

Just looking through the [CI](https://github.com/microsoft/garnet/blob/main/.github/workflows/ci.yml#L7) file you linked.

I've noticed that you correctly try to ignore `.md` files like you want. However, you also then add a `branches` key. Like so:

```
  pull_request:
    **paths-ignore:**
      - '**/*.md'
      **branches:**
      - main
```

What happens here is that if the change does not match any of the paths-ignore patterns, the workflow will proceed to check the branch name. And if the branch name is found then the workflow will run regardless.

Comment: If we don't put branches, then it will take into account all branches which we don't want. The problem is that this CI is REQUIRED to run for the PR to be cleared to merge, but we don't want to require it when .md files are the only ones changed in the PR.  It seems that the PR is not taking into account that paths are ignored in the CI.

Comment: Yep I understand this. I've been looking into it myself, currently and just having a peek around documentation. Like we suspected, (excluding files)[https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/triggering-a-workflow#accessing-and-using-event-properties] should work, but due to needing a specific branch this falls through. The alternative is [Requiring a job to run](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/triggering-a-workflow#accessing-and-using-event-properties) then if that first job finds '.md' files to not trigger the following CI jobs.

Comment: You are saying just removing "main" should be sufficient? 

 I think I might just go this route: "The alternative is Requiring a job to run then if that first job finds '.md' files to not trigger the following CI jobs"

Comment: I think there is a bit disjoint on the problem - I might be confusing things calling it CI when reality it is the workflow. I find the actual workflow to be running how it is supposed to.  Our problem is the interaction between PR and workflow Are you saying if the branch name is found in the PR then it fires off the workflow? That is the problem for us - the PR thinks it is firing it off (when it shouldn't) but it doesn't fire it off and the PR is thinking it should have.

Comment: I did find this: This is indeed a common issue with GitHub Actions. The problem arises because the PR is not aware that certain paths are being ignored in the CI, and it still expects the CI to run.